# How to scrape a collapsable table in RStudio

Tags: r, web-scraping, rstudio, rvest

This web site is summarizes university entrance exam results in 25 detailed tables. Following is results are of Hacettepe Uni. Faculty of Medicine. I like to scrape the table #10 which summarizes which high school has most students in this faculty:

https://yokatlas.yok.gov.tr/lisans.php?y=104810626#

I could not get any data with the conventional R code.

I tried to reach the 10th collapsable table in the site, with the xpath

```
xpath='//*[@id="icerik_1060"]/table'
```

but it resulted in empty cells.

Same code works with success with many html tables of other web sites, no problem. Also I got data positively when I used the following xpaths

```
xpath= '//*[@id="h1060"]/a/h4' or 
xpath= '//*[@id="headingOne"]/a/h4').
```

Here is the code:

```
pkgs = c("magrittr", "httr", "stringr", "jsonlite","tidyverse","rvest","xml2")

for (pkg in pkgs){
  if (!require(pkg, character.only = T)){ 
    install.packages(pkg)
    library(pkg)
  }
}

url <- "https://yokatlas.yok.gov.tr/lisans.php?y=104810626#"
webpage <- read_html(url)

wp <- html_nodes(webpage, xpath= '//*[@id="icerik_1060"]/table')
table <- html_table(wp, header=TRUE, trim=TRUE)
table

lasttable <- html_node(webpage,xpath ='/html/body/footer/div/table') 
table <- html_table(lasttable, header=TRUE, trim=TRUE)
table
```

following piece works properly for the last table at the footer of the page.

```
lasttable <- html_node(webpage,xpath ='/html/body/footer/div/table') 
table <- html_table(lasttable, header=TRUE, trim=TRUE)
table
```

results in:

```
[1] Bize Önerilerinizi İletebilirsiniz:yokatlas@yok.gov.tr                                                           
[2] Girdi Göstergelerindeki bilgiler ÖSYM'den 2015, 2016, 2017 ve 2018 Ağustos ayında alınan verilerden derlenmiştir.
[3] Yükseköğretim Program Atlası©Yükseköğretim Kurulu Bilgi İşlem Daire Başkanlığı                                   
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

but following does not:

```
wp <- html_nodes(webpage, xpath= '//*[@id="icerik_1060"]/table')
table <- html_table(wp, header=TRUE, trim=TRUE)
table
```

results in:

```
list()
```

Here xpaths are different. Table that I cannot get any data is collapsable. May this be the reason ?

Please help what may be problem and how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content is loaded dynamically from another endpoint. You can find this in the network tab when clicking the expand button

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

t <- read_html('https://yokatlas.yok.gov.tr/content/lisans-dynamic/1060.php?y=104810626') %>% html_node("table") %>% html_table(fill=T)
View(t)
```

---

**Sample view:**

[image]

---

[image]

<sub>img link https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPLqP.png</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much ! Nice and simple :)

Comment: Done:) BTW I could not find that network tab, could I have screenshot please ?